# Drunkard walk with payments: when should the drunkard pay?

Tags: random-walk

A drunkard stands at the origin. Each second he goes right with probability $p$, left with probability $q$, and remains still with probability $1-p-q$. When he arrives at $x=+D$ or $x=-D$, he pays $M$ dollars and is transported back to the origin.

Now, there is a new option: at each step, after he knows where he is going to go (left or right), the drunkard has an option to pay $m$ dollars and remain in its place. The drunkard's ultimate goal is to minimize his expeced payment over quadrillion seconds. How should the drunkard decide, in each second, whether to pay?

I think I can solve the special case in which $q=0$, i.e, the drunkard moves only rightwards. In this case, $D$ steps rightwards cost $M$ dollars, so a single step costs in average $M/D$ dollars. Therefore, the drunkard should never pay if $m>M/D$, and always pay if $m<M/D$ <sub>(there may be exceptions at the first few steps or at the quadrillionth step, but they are negligible)</sub>.

However, I am not sure whether the same argument is true for arbitrary $q$.

So, when should the drunkard pay?

Comment: $p+q<1$? So once the drunkard decides to move there are only two outcomes, left and right, so how is $p+q\neq 1$?

Comment: is it a prob. that he stand still?

Comment: Yes, with probability $1-p-q$ he does not move. I clarified it above.

Comment: I still don't understand. If the event "standing still" is probabilistic, and if the drunkard stands still pays $m$ dollars, then where is the decision? There is nothing to optimize! As I understood it at first, at each step the drunkard makes a decision to move or not to. If the answer is yes, then a coin is tossed with two outcomes. Maybe I don't understand the question well.

Comment: Since the decision to pay $m$ dollars is made *after* the type of step (left or right) is known, I don't think there's much to be gained by allowing $1-p-q$ to be nonzero, unless you intend to replace "quadrillion" with $N$.

Comment: Oh, missed it, the decision is made *after* the random value is announced. So there are two types of "standing still". One in which the probabilistic outcome is not moving (with probability $1-p-q$). And one in which the drunkard intentionally decides to pay some money and not move after the random value is announced.

Comment: @Hamed yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a very partial answer, looking at the simplest nontrivial case, $D=2$.

Presumably the quantity of interest can be described as the *average* expenditure per round, where the process is allowed to continue indefinitely (which I take to be the essential meaning of "quadrillion").  With this in mind, we may as well assume that $p+q=1$.  Allowing the possibility of randomly remaining stationary only means you're slowing the average expenditure per round down by a factor of $p+q$, whatever stategy is employed.

In general, since the option to remain stationary isn't decided until *after* the next putative step has been randomly chosen, there is *never* any need to do so unless you are on the $M$-dollar "precipice" at one of the two ends, in this case at $+1$ or $-1$.  At any other point you may as well take the step, incurring no cost, in hopes of reversing it on the next round.

Let's denote by $N$ the average expenditure per step if you *Never* pay to remain stationary.  Under this strategy, you always wind up back at the origin every other round, so it's only on the even numbered rounds, when you're at $\pm1$, that you risk having to pay $M$.  The average expenditure is

$$N={p^2+q^2\over2}M$$

Next, let's denote by $B$ the average expenditure per round if you pay to remain stationary at *Both* $+1$ and $-1$ (if the alternative would take you to $+2$ or $-2$).  This gives a Markov process on the states $\{-1,0,1$} with transition matrix

$$\pmatrix{q&q&0\\p&0&q\\0&p&p}$$

and dominant eigenstate

$${1\over1-pq}\pmatrix{q^2\\pq\\p^2}$$

(Note:  $q^2+pq+p^2=1-pq$.) It follows that the average expenditure per round (in the limit) is

$$B={q^3+p^3\over1-pq}m$$

For example, if $p=q=1/2$, then

$$N={1\over4}M\quad\text{and}\quad B={1\over3}m$$

so the crossover occurs at $m={3\over4}M$. (Note, if $pq=0$, then $N=M/2$ and $B=m$, with a crossover at $m=M/2=M/D$, as the OP observed.)

There are, of course, two more stategies:  pay to remain stationary at $-1$ but not $+1$, and *vice versa*.  Let's denote by $L$ and $R$ the average expenditure per round for these two strategies.  If I've done the algebra correctly, the results are

$$L={p^3\over1+p^2}M+{q^2\over1+p^2}m$$
and
$$R={q^3\over1+q^2}M+{p^2\over1+q^2}m$$

For $p=q=1/2$ we get

$$L=R={1\over10}M+{1\over5}m$$

It's not hard to check that, for $p=q=1/2$, we have $600(N-L)(L-B)=(3M-4m)^2$, which means that the $L$ (and $R$) strategy always lies between the $N$ and $B$ strategies, with crossover at $m={3\over4}M$, so for the classic, symmetric drunkard's walk, one should be willing to pay to remain stationary either Never or a Both ends (which makes sense, by symmetry).  For general $p+q=1$, however, there can be cases when $L$ or $R$ is optimal.

It might be worth looking carefully at the case $D=3$, but hopefully this gives some indication of how things will go.

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even for the case $q=0$ your argument does not work. Suppose $N$ is the number of seconds the drunkard has to walk (a constant).  Let us call each time the drunkard goes all the way to $D$ a tour.

Suppose $k$ tours are completed in $N$ seconds, with respectively $\{n_1, \cdots, n_k\}$ extra times the drunkards has payed. Also suppose the last tour remains incomplete with $\nu$ payups and $\mu$ non-payups. Then the total money paid will be
$$
P=Mk+\nu m+m\sum_{j=1}^{k} n_j
$$
Now the $j$th tour takes $D+n_j$ seconds. And the last incomplete tour is $\nu+\mu$ seconds, with $\mu<D$ of course. So the above is conditioned on
$$
N=Dk +\mu +\nu + \sum_{j=1}^{k} n_j
$$
This is now truly a conditional optimization problem. Now suppose $m>M/D$, you suggest never paying a single penny. Your payout then will be $M\lfloor N/D\rfloor$. But if instead, in each tour, we pay exactly $n$ times, and not paying anything in the last incomplete tour,
$$
N=(D+n)k+\mu\Longrightarrow k=\lfloor N/(D+n)\rfloor
$$
The payup is then $P_n=M\lfloor N/(D+n)\rfloor+mn$. The payup you propose is the $n=0$ case. For example suppose $N=2D\ell$ for some large $\ell$ and $n=D$. Then
$$
P_0=\ell M+\ell M, \qquad P_D=M\ell +Dm
$$
Clearly if $\ell M>Dm$ then $P_D$ case is much better. This happens when $\ell>Dm/M$, or $N>2D^2m/M$. This actually tells you $m>M/D$ or not, never paying up is not a good idea, if $N$ is large enough.

Your estimate for $m<M/D$ is much better. Suppose one goes with the strategy of always paying. Then the payup is $P'=mN$. In the same example as before this is worse that $P_D$ unless the condition $(2mD-M)\ell<Dm$ is satisfied. Considering $\ell\ggg 1$, the condition is more or less limited to cases when $m<M/2D$, which is similar to your estimate in this example.

However suppose instead $N=sD\ell$ with $s$ a small integer and $n=(s-1)D$. Then a similar analysis shows that
$$
P=M\ell+(s-1)Dm
$$
Comparing with $P'=sD\ell M$ (always paying case), the condition for $P'$ being better than $P$ is now $m<M/sD$. I guess my point is, this is a very complicated problem even in case of $q=0$. The behavior is very sensitive to the values of $m,M,D,N$.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! But I think there is a mistake in your expression for $P_n$ - it should be $(M+mn)k$. Then the following analysis is much simpler: $P_n = (M+mn)N/(D+n)$ (I am neglecting the final incomplete tour since it is negligible relative to the quadrillion rounds...). Taking the derivative of $P_n$ as a function of $n$ gives that the derivative is positive if $m > M/D$ and negative if $m < M/D$, so in the former case you want $n$ as small as possible (0) and in the latter case you want it as large as possible ($N$).